# Curl exit immediately if no internet

Tags: bash, curl, array

I want to fetch some apis from github.

so this is the code

```
array=(link1 link2 link3 link4)
readarray -t item < <(for i in ${array[@]}
      do curl -s "$i" | jq '.tag_name'
      done)
```

and then I can fetch the data from the **item**.

But the problem is if there is some links left to fetch, curl just stuck there.

I want it to exit immediately and instead of previous data, I need it to print some text like "error" or get its exitcode so that I can implement some logic in case of any fail.

provide a efficient solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read all URLs with one `curl` invocation and use option `--fail-early` to
exit immediately on the first detected transfer error. Add `--max-time` to abort each transfer after x seconds and `--connect-timeout` if you want to restrict the connection time.

The item array will be empty in case of an error, you could check that.

```
urls=(link1 link2 link3 link4)
readarray -t item < <(
    curl -s --fail-early --connect-timeout 10 --max-time 120 "${urls[@]}" |
    jq '.tag_name')

if [ "${#item[@]}" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Uh, failed to fetch data." >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `curl -f` option to exit immediately if the response code is greater than or equal to 400. Also, you can add the `-w` option to capture the exit code and `-o` option to redirect the output to `/dev/null` to avoid printing the response to the console.

```
array=(link1 link2 link3 link4)

for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    response=$(curl -f -w '%{http_code}' -o /dev/null "$i")
    if [ "$response" -ge 400 ]; then
        echo "error"
    else
        curl -s "$i" | jq '.tag_name'
    fi
done
```